# Python - выбор конкретного количества слов из представленного списка

Tags: python-3.x

До этого спрашивал как сохранять слова в файл, странные вопросы получаются, но не суть xD

В общем, допустим у меня есть файл words.txt, и в нем есть список различных слов. Мне надо выбрать неопределенное количество рандомных слов из этого списка. Слова записаны следующим образом:

```
привет
как
дела
это
пример
```

Их конечно же побольше, но суть думаю ясна. Отсюда надо выбрать неопределенное количество, думаю через random.randint(5, 35). Как это реализовать? С циклами и всем прочим плохо знаком, поэтому даже идей нет.

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, что значит `выбрать неопределенное количество слов`

Comment: Допустим, у меня есть список с 120 словами.
Из всех этих слов мне нужно выбрать какое то количество рандомных, это самое количество будет устанавливать метод random.randint(5, 45). То есть от 5 до 45 пяти слов мне нужно. И все это записать в переменную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно попробовать так:

```
import random

file = "FILE_PATH"
words = []
random_words = []
num = random.randint(1, 5)  # рандомное число
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words.append(line)  # добавляем свои слова в список

for i in set(random.choices(words, k=num)):
    random_words.append(i)  # добавляем рандомные слова в список

newString = " ".join([line.rstrip() for line in random_words]
print(newString) # строка для отправки
```

Comment: Вроде как работает, но мне нужно что бы вот эти слова сразу поместились в переменную. То есть, допустим. В файле слова:

привет
как
дела
это
тест

Он выбрал рандомные, и получилось "привет тест это"

UPD: Где я привел пример слов, они через строчку. В комментарии нельзя так написать

Comment: Не очень понимаю постановки вопроса. Как можно все слова в одну переменную? Или каждое слово в отдельную переменную? Или в список их? Уточните.

Comment: Наверное в список, я пишу бота для различных бесед. И вот мне как раз нужно что бы он с файла words.txt выбирал рандомные слова, складывал их в переменную, или список, как удобнее, и отправлял их.

Comment: Чтобы добавить их в список нужно создать ещё один пустой список random_words = []. И вместо последнего принта написать random_words.append(i).

Comment: Возможно, это искомое решение. Подредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: я уже наверное надоел, извини, но я хочу уже закончить это.
В общем, теперь почти все отлично, он генерирует как надо. То есть print(i, end=" ") генерирует как надо, без каких либо символов, все отлично. Но когда я отправляю сообщение(я для вк делаю) то там только одно слово. Первое. Я так понял, что все эти слова содержаться в переменной i ?

Comment: @FruthyzGang типа такого? Отредачил ещё разок

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо больше <3333

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на set() во втором for-цикле. Он делает все рандомные слова уникальными. Если слова должны повторяться (Или должны иметь такую возможность), то сет нужно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint

string = """В общем, допустим у меня есть файл
words.txt, и в нем есть список различных слов.
Мне надо выбрать неопределенное количество рандомных
слов из этого списка. Слова записаны следующим образом
"""

_list = string.split()

random_list = [ _list[randint(0, len(_list) -1) ] for _ in range(randint(1, len(_list)))  ]

print(random_list)
```

Comment: Вроде генерирует, но есть несколько проблем.
Извиняюсь что сам не фикшу, так как в чужом коде плохо разбираюсь.
Генерирует он с посторонними знаками, то есть ['следующим', 'слов.', 'записаны', 'Мне', 'следующим', 'в', 'нем', 'у', 'списка.', 'записаны', 'этого', 'следующим'].
2) Вы указали string это переменная. А у меня слова в файле, это получается сначало надо открыть этот файл, потом все слова которые в нем есть записать в переменную string?

Comment: @FruthyzGang да, прочитайте файл в переменную `string` и вперед.

Comment: Вот, теперь он их берет с файла. А что делать с лишними знаками?

Comment: @FruthyzGang я не понимаю о каких лишних знаках вы говорите? У вас в файле есть какие-то лишние знаки?

Comment: Нет, я не про это. Смотрите, генерирует он слова правильно, но вот таким образом: ['слово', еще', 'какое', 'то', 'вот', 'так']. Я говорю именно про знаки "[ ' ,". Можно ли их как то убрать, что бы оставались только слова?